# Conditional expectation equality and definition

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be A real random variable. $A$ is an event.

Is the following equality correct?

$E[X 1_A] = E[X | A] P(A)$

In particular, if $P(A) = 0$, is the equality still true?

Comment: If $P(A)=0$, then $E(X\mid A)$ does not exist hence no, the identity in your post does not hold.

Comment: @Did: Hm it depends on how one defines conditional expectation. For example if $X,Y \sim U([0,1])$ then $E[XY \mid Y=1/3] = E[X/3] = 1/6$. It is usually possible to similarly patch the typical definition of conditional probability and **define** $P[X \mid A] = P[X]$ whenever $P[A] = 0$, to preserve the identity $P[B \mid A] P[A] = P[B \land A]$ in all cases. This can be useful sometimes to avoid corner cases.

Comment: @user21820 The objects $E(X\mid A)$ and $E(X\mid Y)$, hence also $E(X\mid Y=y)$, are quite different. Note that $$E(X\mid Y=y)\ne E(X\mid\{Y=y\})$$ I know no reference using the RHS when $P(Y=y)=0$ (and there are good reasons to avoid this abuse of notation).

Comment: @Did: At least here $A$ is an event, and $(Y=1/3)$ is also an event in the appropriate probability space for my example. As for references to such a convention, I don't have any off-hand but I found it exceedingly useful in information theory such as in definition and manipulation of conditional entropy. But I'm curious to know what are your reasons to avoid it?

Comment: @user21820 Precisely to maintain the distinction between the elementary conditional expectation $E(X\mid\{Y=y\})$, valid when $P(Y=y)\ne0$, and $E(X\mid Y=y)=u(y)$ where $u$ solves $E(X\mid Y)=u(Y)$. But I can imagine that researchers knowing what they are doing might find useful to trespass these boundaries... :-)